# Fixed navigation + anchor scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get scrolling to work based on id anchors.
Which works great.
The problem is that I have 50px worth of fixed top navigation, which means that scrolling is 50px to short (so to speak)

This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var url = document.location.toString();
        var target = url.split('#')[1];   
    location.hash = target;
</script>
```

I've tried using `.offset().top-50;` but keep getting

> offset(...) is undefined

Any help would greatly appreciated

Comment: Offset should not go undefined. It would either be null or an Object. Can you input us more code which may help to identify the solution.

Comment: there is no more code? what i tried was location.hash=target.offset()...

Comment: Try $(target).offset() ?

Comment: $(...).offset(...) is undefined

Comment: Undefined comes only when the function in the library is not present. So can you check whether jQuery is loaded or not.